# A Cryptic Dirty Dozen: Do your best!

Tags: cryptic-clues, literature

1. > Age a herb salad for a cat. (8)
2. > Wolfmother confused a shark. (6)
3. > Alias around the Spanish leader (5)
4. > The Colonel runs through that hibiscus patch (5)
5. > Ursine stench holds soothing plant that's been trimmed (5)
6. > "Gross!" said the Porcupine. (4)
7. > Prohibit endless challenge: Record monkeys. (5-3)
8. > Missouri woman's thousand and third element. Boy! (6)
9. > Haphazardly I go. Unlike the Orangutan (4,5)
10. > Bengali Dancing? Hank's Here! (5, 4)
11. > The Swiss psychiatrist and the French reserve our theme. (3,6,4)
12. > Storyteller rewrote rigid pun, darkly. (7, 7)

Bonus:

> Tangled tubes occur in my volunteer position (3, 7)

(How does this relate to the theme?)

Comment: 8. should be (6), not (5)?

Comment: 11. should be (3,6,4) as well, I think

Comment: And 12. should be (7, 7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Age a herb salad for a cat. (8)

> Bagheera
>  (age a herb)*

Wolfmother confused a shark. (6)

> Raksha
>  (a shark)*

Alias around the Spanish leader (5)

> Akela
>  AKA around EL

The Colonel runs through that hibiscus patch (5)

> Hathi
>  t(hat hi)biscus

Ursine stench holds soothing plant that's been trimmed (5)

> Baloo
>  BO around ALO(e)

"Gross!" said the Porcupine. (4)

> Ikki
>  Homophone of Icky

Prohibit endless challenge: Record monkeys. (5-3)

> Bandar-log
>  BAN+DAR(e)+LOG

Missouri woman's thousand and third element. Boy! (5)

> Mowgli
>  MO+W+G+Li

Haphazardly I go. Unlike the Orangutan (4,5)

> King Louie
>  (I go unlike)*

Bengali Dancing? Hank's Here! (5, 4)

> Shere Khan
>  (hanks here)*

The Swiss psychiatrist and the French reserve our theme. (3,5,4)

> The Jungle Book
>  THE+Jung+LE+BOOK

Storyteller rewrote rigid pun, darkly. (7, 6)

> Rudyard Kipling
>  (rigid pun darkly)*

Tangled tubes occur in my volunteer position (3, 7)

> Cub scouter?
>  (tubes occur)*

(How does this relate to the theme?)

> Mowgli was a mancub?

Comment: All correct.  The "how it relates" may be national organization specific.